# I get error java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '!'

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I have the following string

```
String pat = "HelloWorld#$%!";

@FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(text(), 'Best Choice')]")
WebElement button;

final String format = String.format("%s", pat);
final String format = String.format("%s=!", pat);
button.getText().contains(format);
```

When I'm trying to compare my button with text fails with

> java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '!'

Comment: % is already used by format specifiers so it requires an additional % to display that character. You can try String pat = "HelloWorld#$%%!"; OR pat = pat.replace("%", "%%");

Comment: Could you apply the suggestion in the comment and share if it works or do you face any other error ?